# Update image pixels faster

Tags: java, image-processing

I am making an image editing like program, and when I want to edit large images it really starts to slow down. What is a good way to edit large image quickly? This example adjusts the image's brightness, it works, but when I get large images such as 3456x2304 its really slow.

I have a slider, which calls this function every time it moves.

```
// Slider in a dialog box
private void sldBrightnessStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
    // Get the position of the slider
    int val = sldBrightness.getValue();
    // Set the text in the textbox
    txtBrightness.setText("" + val);
    // New Brightness class (see below)
    Brightness adjustment = new Brightness();
    adjustment.amount(val);
    adjustment.applyFilter();
    // get the result built by applyFilter();
    Canvas.preview = Preview.getImage();
    // Update main program
    this.getParent().repaint();
}
```

Then the filter:

```
package pocketshop.graphics.adjustments;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import pocketshop.Canvas;
import pocketshop.graphics.Colors;
import pocketshop.graphics.Preview;

public class Brightness{

    protected int amount = 0;

    public void amount(int amount){
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void applyFilter(){
        int width = Canvas.image.getWidth();
        int height = Canvas.image.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];

        Canvas.image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
        for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++){
            int pixel = pixels[i];
            //int pixel = Canvas.image.getRGB(x, y);
            int red = Colors.red(pixel);
            int green = Colors.green(pixel);
            int blue = Colors.blue(pixel);

            red += amount;
            if(red > 255){
                red = 255;
            }else if(red < 0){
                red = 0;
            }

            green += amount;
            if(green > 255){
                green = 255;
            }else if(green < 0){
                green = 0;
            }

            blue += amount;
            if(blue > 255){
                blue = 255;
            }else if(blue < 0){
                blue = 0;
            }
            pixels[i] = Colors.rgba(red, green, blue);
        }
        //BrightnessContrastDialog.preview.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        img.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
        Preview.setImage(img);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are individually adjusting 8 million pixels.  That is going to be slow.  Usually, this type of thing is accomplished quickly by performing the operation in the GPU on the image in graphics memory.

Comment: Any suggestions how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the picture is presented for user in order to give immediate feedback of changes that are made, what you can do us display downsampled version of picture and perform the brightness change to it while slider is moving which will be fast. Once user is satisfied with the value she selected using slider you can apply the change to original image. You can add apply button or something

Answer (score 3):

> I have a slider, which calls this function every time it moves.

Don't adjust the image until the slider stops moving. I don't know Swing, but I'm betting there is a test for `evt` which says whether it is moving or has stopped.

The way you have it, applyFilter may be called 100 times or more as the slider is moved.

Comment: Even doing that after it stops and adjusts it still takes about 2 - 5 seconds.

Comment: + You can update only preview image, big image can be processed in background thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you investigate [OpenCL](https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl) and its Java binding, [JOCL](http://www.jocl.org/).  OpenCL is a library for interacting directly with the GPU on various different graphics cards.  JOCL is a Java binding library for the OpenCL API.

Fair warning, this may be much more than you want to tackle, as you will be working at a much lower level than Swing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it looks like you are using a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) of type BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB. This means that the BufferedImage is using a WritableRaster that is using a DataBuffer of type DataBufferInt. In its simplest form a DataBufferInt is nothing more than a wrapper around an int[]. If you can get a hold of the BufferedImage that the Canvas is using then get its WritableRaster and from there get the DataBufferInt:

```
WritableRaster raster = Canvas.image.getRaster();
DataBufferInt dataBuffer = (DataBufferInt)raster.getDataBuffer();
int[] pixels = dataBuffer.getData();
```

Now that you have the int[] that represents the pixels you can just loop over it and change the components:

```
for (int i = 0, len = pixels.len; i < len; ++i) {
  int pixel = pixels[i];

  int red = ((pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) + amount;
  if (red < 0) red = 0 else if (red > 255) red = 255;

  int green = ((pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) + amount;
  if (green < 0) green = 0 else if (green > 255) green = 255;

  int blue = (pixel & 0x000000FF) + amount;
  if (blue < 0) blue = 0 else if (blue > 255) blue = 255;

  pixels[i] = (pixels[i] & 0xFF000000) + (red << 16) + (green << 8) + blue;
}
```

This means that the pixels in the BufferedImage that the Preview has are being changed in-place without having to create another int[] of new pixels and another BufferedImage.

I am not sure if this will work but many times it helps in Java to cut out the middle-man and don't create as many objects.

If this does not work then look into [Java Advanced Imaging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/jai-142803.html).